# beforeShowDay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to disable all days except those I send in variable `days` but It not working...

```
if (dias !=null && dias!="" && dias!='undefined'){  
        var days  = dias.split(',');    
        //$('#sandbox-container-'+num).datepicker('setDates', days);

        $('#sandbox-container-'+num).datepicker({


            beforeShowDay: function(d) {
                var dmy = (d.getMonth()+1)
                if(d.getMonth()<9) 
                    dmy="0"+dmy; 
                dmy+= "/"; 

                if(d.getDate()<10) dmy+="0"; 
                    dmy+=d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear(); 

                console.log(dmy+' : '+($.inArray(dmy, days)));

                if ($.inArray(dmy, days) != -1) {
                    return [true, "","Available"]; 
                } else{
                     return [false,"","unAvailable"]; 
                }
            }

        }).datepicker('setDates', days).attr("readonly", "readonly");

    }
```

Comment: When you say days do mean the days of all months (Only the days 17,18 of all months be active) or do you mean something like: I only want this dates ["17/05/2018", "18/05/2018", etc]?

Comment: @William-H-M Second option, I want specific dates

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case you can use the `beforeShowDay` and then check everyday against your array and see if some of the options are valid ones.

As you can see we check for the day we get on the function and start to compare if is on the array then return true an the day will be active.

Now this have a little problem is that the format differs a little because am use JavaScript date, but it's easily solve using [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/) [*will do later*]

```js
var enableDates = ['17/5/2018', '18/5/2018', '19/5/2018', '7/5/2018'];


$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
  format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  autoclose: true,
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var currentDate =
      date.getDate() + '/' +
      (date.getMonth() + 1) +
      '/' + date.getFullYear();
    return (enableDates.indexOf(currentDate) != -1)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<br/>
<div class="span5 col-md-5" id="sandbox-container">
  <input class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still not working. When I try to debug beforeShowDay function It not go inside... Maybe, the problem is variable date always undefined. I'm using the datepicker inside a ``sandbox-container`` not in a normal input field

Comment: @Raider Well by itself the `sandbox-container` shouldn't give any problem, could it be that there's some console error? See update code